# Reusing EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm starting with Amazon EC2 usage for some ML training on a GPU.

What I want to do after I launch and ssh to my EC2 (Spot) instance:

- clone my GitHub repository (first setup access)
- download dataset
- prepare dataset (unzip, copy to aproprate directories, etc.)
- prepare python environment
- run the training

My question is: once I stop the Amazon EC2 instance, will I be able to reuse my setup work, or it will all be lost, so once I want to do training again, I would have to do the whole setup again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can stop and restart EC2 instances but only those that are EBS-backed. This applies to [persistent spot instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/amazon-ec2-spot-instances-stopped-started-similar-to-on-demand-instances/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20stop%20and%20start,our%20technical%20documentation%20or%20FAQs.) as well as on-demand instances. Note that 'persistent' is not the default option for spot instances, but you can request a persistent spot instance under Advanced options > Request type.

See [Stop and start your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html).

Use [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html#display-instance-root-device-type) to check that the root device type of your EC2 instance is EBS or use [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html#display-ami-root-device-type) to check that the root device type of an AMI is EBS.

Comment: Thanks. The link "these steps" is somehow misleading: I don't have anything listed under AMIs, instead I went to my instance and there I followed the link under "AMI ID" which eventualy led me to the info I wanted: "Root device type: EBS".

Comment: You're right, apologies. That link shows steps for checking an AMI, not an EC2 instance. Have updated answer with a better link.

Comment: One more thing: when requesting for the Spot instance, one should make sure to select `Advanced options` and under `Request type` choose: `Persistent`. Otherwise,  by default you'll be given the `One-time` instance which cannot be Stoped, only Terminated - in which case all data is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to physically stop the instance yourself, however you can choose to have the instance stopped when a [spot instance interruption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html) occurs.

And in that case, yes, you will be able to reuse the setup. From [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/amazon-ec2-spot-instances-stopped-started-similar-to-on-demand-instances/):

> The start/stop provides you more control over your Spot Instances in addition to the existing interruption behavior. When you stop your Spot Instance, the EBS root device and attached EBS volumes are saved and their data persists. Upon restart, the EBS root device is restored from its prior state, previously attached data volumes are reattached, and the instance retains its instance ID.

> This feature is available for persistent Spot requests. You will not be charged for instance usage while your instance is stopped. EBS volume storage is charged at standard rates. You should cancel your Spot request at any time to terminate stopped instances. This feature is only available for instances with an Amazon EBS volume as their root device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be able to reuse everything you have configured and will not need to set it up again.

You can see in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instances-and-amis.html#instance-stopping-starting-terminating

> When an instance is stopped, the instance performs a normal shutdown, and then transitions to a stopped state. All of its Amazon EBS volumes remain attached, and you can start the instance again at a later time.